# Override login form style

Tags: forms, theming, users

How do I style the login form in the zen sub-theme neptune. I'm kind of confused if I'm supposed to override the css styles. I'm not able to figure out how to change the login form wrapper div and the styles inside it.

Comment: The web browser inspector is an invaluable friend for this kind of stuff.

Comment: how really depends on the extent to which you want to customize it. what exactly are you trying to change?